# iCloud & Work + Personal Account

Tags: icloud

I'm curious to see how others are managing iCloud between their work computers and iOS devices (especially in the WFH world).  There are some things like AirPod Pro Connection, Notes, Apple Watch Unlocking, HomeKit, Sidecar, possibly some iMessage - that makes me want to connect my work laptop to my personal iCloud account (I have two accounts currently and share some Notes folders, etc.).

I'm not under the impression that my employer is poking around my laptop but, I do think it seems best to keep personal information off of my work laptop.

How are other people doing this?

Comment: I am asking about Auto Unlock here (using Apple Watch to unlock Mac) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428892/setting-up-auto-unlock-on-other-mac-having-a-different-main-icloud-account I haven't found out a way to do it, it seems like it takes adding the exactly same iCloud account that is on the Watch to be the main iCloud account on the work Mac and that is something I don't think anyone would do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not connect my iCloud account to my work-assigned MacBook Pro. It is against company policy for starters (although not actually blocked) and risks intermingling my work and personal lives.

Sidecar is the only thing that is a non-starter without it, the rest are things that would simply be more convenient if you were signed in. If I needed Sidecar–or really wanted one of the other services, I probably would sign in, but turn off all services–especially iCloud Drive and Find my Mac.