# Setting up Auto Unlock on other Mac having a different main iCloud account

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-watch

I'm using Auto Unlock to unlock my personal Mac because my personal Mac obviously has the same iCloud account in macOS as the Apple Watch I'm using.

Now I have a work Mac and I need to use another main iCloud account in that one for obvious reasons, but it would be swell to be able to setup Auto Unlock on this Mac as well, are there any ways to do this without exposing too much of my personal iCloud information to the work Mac?

What I tried:

- Adding my personal iCloud account to "Internet Accounts" in "System Preferences". It didn't seem to work as the Auto Unlock toggle was not available from "Security & Privacy", as noted here https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl4f800a42/mac

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410363/icloud-work-personal-account?rq=1

Comment: Don't mix your personal information on your work Mac.

Comment: Obviously this is something I understand thank you, I wonder if you understand the reason why Auto Unlock would be useful do you not?